# Typescript Implementation Signature for Overloaded Function with Tuples of Multiple Lengths

Tags: typescript, tuples, overloading, es6-promise, typescript-generics

Consider the interface defining [`Promise.all`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d5a646eb661f5c68b4b9b01da5bea771f354a6bf/src/lib/es2015.promise.d.ts#L15-L93):

```js
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10>(values: readonly [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike<T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>, T7 | PromiseLike<T7>, T8 | PromiseLike<T8>, T9 | PromiseLike<T9>, T10 | PromiseLike<T10>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10]>;
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>(values: readonly [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike<T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>, T7 | PromiseLike<T7>, T8 | PromiseLike<T8>, T9 | PromiseLike<T9>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9]>;
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(values: readonly [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike<T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>, T7 | PromiseLike<T7>, T8 | PromiseLike<T8>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8]>;
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>(values: readonly [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike<T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>, T7 | PromiseLike<T7>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7]>;
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(values: readonly [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike<T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6]>;
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(values: readonly [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike<T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]>;
all<T1, T2, T3, T4>(values: readonly [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike<T4>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4]>;
all<T1, T2, T3>(values: readonly [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3]>;
all<T1, T2>(values: readonly [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>]): Promise<[T1, T2]>;
all<T>(values: readonly (T | PromiseLike<T>)[]): Promise<T[]>;
```

What is the [implementation signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature) that would satisfy all these overloads? Neither `function all(values)` nor `function all(...values)` work.

Comment: What do you mean by implementation signature? Would be something like `all(values: any[]): any` if it wasn't already a built-in.

Comment: The implementation signature is the final signature provided in the overloads, which must encompass all of them: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature

Comment: @MingweiSamuel's `all(values:any[]):any` is working so far.  Weird that `function all(...values)` didn't -- I thought those two were effectively the same.

Comment: `fn(...values: any[])` would accept `fn(a, b, c, d, ...)`, not what we want, but `fn(values: any[])` would accept `fn([ a, b, c, d, ... ])` -- single array argument which is what we want. You could also do some weird unpacking like `fn([ ...values ]: any[])` but that's kinda pointless.